# Login page shows blank

Tags: php

The login page on a project i'm currently fixing up shows blank.  i tried echoing some words to find out where the fault lied.  I found out that commenting out the below piece of code made it to display.

```
elseif( isset($_POST['do_login'] ) ){ //Login user

    $email = (isset($_POST['login']) && is_string($_POST['login'])
                && strlen($_POST['login'])<100)?$_POST['login'] : null;
    $password  = (isset($_POST['password']) && is_string($_POST['password'])
                && strlen($_POST['password'])<100)?$_POST['password'] : null;
    $remember  = isset($_POST['chkremember']) ? true : false;

    $result = $auth->login($email, $password, $remember);

    switch($result){
        case 1:
            $msg = 'You have successfully logged in.'
            break;    
        case 2:
            $msg = 'Your account has not yet been confirmed. <br/> Please check the e-mail message sent by us and click the confirmation code to validate this account. <a href="user_login.php?view=resend&resend_email='.$email.'">resend activation e-mail</a>';
            break;
        case 3:
            $msg = 'Your account is not enabled!';
            break;
        case 4:
            $msg = 'Account with given login credentials does not exist!';
            break;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me figiure out what's wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: What do you mean by "blank"? Completely white pages? If yes, have a look at your error logs.

Comment: Turn on errors in your php.ini file and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: There seems to be code missing! You start with an `elseif` here.

Comment: my bet is that $_POST['do_login'] is not set. best way to know it to to print_r($_POST) before the if. Moreover, this piece of code sets the variable $msg, but does appear to print nothing when $msg=1 (login ok). There may be some more php after the code you posted thou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 case 1: $msg = 'You have successfully logged in.'   break;
```

Semicolon missing before break;

Comment: Thanks that fixed that.. i overlooked that while trying to fix bigger issues with the script ....  please see this question if you'd like to help me out with the bigger issues i have with this script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106766/user-logs-out-by-itself

Answer (score 2):

in `case 1`, you miss `;` before `break`.